# Deferred Object catch() method Chaining

Tags: jquery, es6-promise

I am new to jQuery. I am currently learning deferred objects in jQuery. I am having issue while running my jQuery code.

The problem is when my deferred object return in resolved state it is calling `successCallBack` function which is called in `done()` but after that function which is define after `catch()` is also getting executed.

Why this is happening?

Thank you for any kinds of suggestion.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btnLoadImage').click(function () {

        var dfd = getImages(); // Returns Deferred object

        dfd.always(alwaysCallBack('Ajax is Called'));

        dfd.progress(progressCallback);

        dfd.done(successCallBack);

        dfd.catch(errorCallback).then(function () {
            console.log(dfd.state());
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.gallery').empty();
                $('.gallery').append('<center><input type="button" id="btnTryAgain" style="width:200px" class="btn btn-primary" value="Try Again" /></center>');
            }, 3000);
        });
        
    });

    $('.gallery').on('click', '#btnTryAgain', function () {

        console.log('Hello');
        $('.gallery').empty();
        $('#btnLoadImage').click();

    })  

    function getImages() {

        var dfd = new $.Deferred();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=car',
            dataType : 'json',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', API_KEY);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept','application/json');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                dfd.notify('Loading...');
               setTimeout(function () { dfd.resolve(data) }, 3000);

            },
            error: function (error) {
                dfd.notify('Loading...');
                setTimeout(function () { dfd.reject('Response Rejected.') }, 3000);
                
            }
        });

        return dfd.promise();
    }

    function successCallBack(data) {

        $('.gallery').empty();

        data.photos.forEach(photo => {
            const item = document.createElement('div');
            item.classList.add('item');
            item.innerHTML = `<img src="${photo.src.medium}">`;
            $('.gallery').append(item);
        });
    }

    function errorCallback(errorMessage) {
        $('.gallery').empty();
        $('.gallery').append('<p><h1 style="color:red">' + errorMessage + '</h1></p>');
    }

    function progressCallback(progressMessage) {

        $('.gallery').empty();
        $('.gallery').append('<p><h1>' + progressMessage + '</h1></p>');
    }

    function alwaysCallBack(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }      
});
```

Deferred is resolved:

[image]

**Function which is define after `catch()` is called.**

[image]

Comment: This code just looks way more complicated than necessary which is probably related to why it isn't working correctly.  `$.ajax()` already returns a promise.  Just use that promise rather than making your own and then manually resolving or rejecting it.  Don't mix a plain callback interface with a promise interface.  If you want a promise out of the ajax call, just use the promise interface that's built-in.

Comment: But I want us deffered object in jquery when i am fetching data from api.Any other real life example where deffered can be used?

Comment: Also, this `dfd.always(alwaysCallBack('Ajax is Called'));` should be this `dfd.always(function() {alwaysCallBack('Ajax is Called')});`.  You have to pass a function reference.